# Listing out the missing Ids from an auto incrementing primarykey

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a table Users which has a primary key user_id which is auto incremented when we insert a user_details.Now I've a requirement where in I need to list out all the missing(or deleted) user_ids.
I've tried it this way.

```
DECLARE @NUMBER BIGINT = (SELECT MIN(USER_ID) FROM USERS)

DECLARE @MAX BIGINT = (SELECT MAX(USER_ID) FROM USERS)

CREATE TABLE TEMP_USERS (USER_ID BIGINT)

WHILE @NUMBER <= @MAX
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEMP_USERS
        VALUES(@NUMBER);

    SET @NUMBER = @NUMBER+1;
END

SELECT USER_ID from TEMP_USERS 
EXCEPT 
SELECT USER_ID from USERS
```

But It's taking too long.
Is there an alternate way to increase the performance?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: the requirement is quite odd; if you need to know the missing values in a key sequence usually you want to use an autoincrement field for something it is not suitable for. what does your execution plan say? where is the bottleneck? the less the information, the vaguer the answer. as a wild guest with no guarantee try to use a join instead of `EXCEPT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL 2005+. Then you can do this:

```
DECLARE @NUMBER  BIGINT =(SELECT MIN(USER_ID) from USERS)
DECLARE @MAX BIGINT =(SELECT MAX(USER_ID) from USERS)

;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT @NUMBER UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < @MAX)
SELECT
    Nbrs.n AS USERID
FROM
    Nbrs
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL FROM USERS
    WHERE USERS.USER_ID=Nbrs.n
)
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

**Update**

To address the comment. What does `MAXRECURSION` do in this case. When we are using a recursive CTE function there is a possiblility that you write it in a way that it never ends. The servers `MAXRECURSION` is 100. This can be overridden by using a hint that it should not take the servers `MAXRECURSION`.

When we use 0 then it do not have any `MAXRECURSION`. If we would not set `MAXRECURSION` then after 100 rows it will crash and throw and exception that the `MAXRECURSION` has been meet.

Because we can expect that the OP has more the 100 missing user id in the sequence we need to indicate that we want to keep doing the recursion until `n < @MAX`

Comment: Might want to add MAXRECURSION

Comment: @MarkPM : You are right. I updated the answer. Good like that?

Comment: what does OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0) means here? Can anyone explain?

Comment: @Arion...Thanks a ton but I had to make a small change and use EXCEPT instead of where NOT EXISTS as it Didn't provide the required output.